# Can SQL server send message to external JMS based application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want SQL server to send message to external application, Is that possible with SQL server?

I did google a lot but don't find useful material/Link. Any appropriate answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAISERROR for what you want.

```
RAISERROR('My Error Message',0,1)
```

This will work if the external application runs a query (like a stored procedure) and the query has this line. So for instance if you know the application runs `sp_sample`, then in sp_sample :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_sample
AS
BEGIN
    --Procedure normal code
    RAISERROR('My Error Message',0,1)
END
```

This will execute the code (an INSERT for instance) and then send the message back to the application.

Comment: our external application doesn't have capable of execute query.

Answer (score 0):

In theory is possible, because SQL Server can host CLR procedures and these procedures, if granted EXTERNAL_ACCESS permisssion, can do pretty much anything they please, including calling web services or JMS apps.

But is not recommend, for many reasons (performance, security, maintenability, deployment and configuration, troubleshooting and many more) . Use an external application to do your communication and let SQL Server just manage data.